# No harm be upon you

Tags: idiom-requests, popular-refrains

This is used to comfort the ill in Arabic, among other sayings. This however is very common.

It is however also used to inquire about something that might be wrong before it is said, but by just sensing that there might be, as a wish that everything, God willing, be alright. It is abridged to 'No harm?'

> 1: "I'm feeling dizzy and I think I'm going to be ill."
>   
>  2: "No harm be upon you/your soul."

This following example pertains to the second usage.

> 1: "I can't believe what happened today."
>   
>  2: "May it be of no real harm/no real harm" (or simply, "No harm"), "what's wrong, what happened?"

Realize it is sort of a prayer to hope everything is okay. The longer version is used, but the latter is commoner.

Is there any saying or idiom akin to this in English?

Comment: [*Knock on wood*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knocking_on_wood)? See alsl [alomancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alomancy).

Comment: @AMR, this has nothing to do with Islam. This phrase is an Arabic saying. Way before Islam. Christian arab say this, all arabs do. How does 'God speedpertain to it, I'm lost.

Comment: Misread what you wrote.

Comment: Maybe "*bless you*"? (or as @BiscuitBoy suggests, "*God forbid*")

Answer (score 1):

The closest idiom I can think of is ***[God forbid](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/God+forbid)***

*Meaning*

> May God prevent something from happening or being the case. Also, ***heaven forbid***.

[Dictionary.com]

**Usage Example**

> Person A: I'm feeling dizzy and I think I'm going to be ill!
>
> Person B: Oh dear! ***God forbid*** that you actually fall ill during such a critical time.